# Don't understand GCC compiler behaviour conditional expression (test) ? value 1 : value 2

Tags: c, gcc

Strange compiler behaviour? Is it a bug. With GCC on linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NSIM 1

int main()
{
  printf("%d\n\n",(2 +(NSIM==1)?0:99));
  return 0;
}
```

gave the output 0   (NSIM=1)

but

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NSIM 1

int main()
{
  printf("%d\n\n",(2 +((NSIM==1)?0:99)));
  return 0;
}
```

gave the output 2

Is this a bug in the compiler - to my mind they should both give 2

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: `Is this a bug in the compiler` 99.99% of times it isn't.

Comment: You (especially as a beginner) literally  **never** find a bug in the GCC compiler. If there is a strange behaviour, you probably wrote bad code.

Comment: @DeiDei thanks for response...

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting. This is well-written with a compilable example and expected and documented behaviour. Granted, the assertion that gcc might have a bug as simple as this is a touch incendiary!

Comment: @Bathsheba - I don't understand either - but then clearly I don't understand much at all !!!  ....  lots of downvoting and I included minimal compilable code... clearly I am too much of a noob... :-)

Comment: @tom: We ought not downvote on the grounds of obviousness. The questions on general relativity I used to ask my professor were obvious to him for sure. Obviousness is subjective.

Comment: @Bathsheba - ok so I tried to reduce the incendiary nature of the post by changing the title to something milder....

Comment: ok as the community votes I will delete the post as inappropriate.... if it is just downvoted out....  at least I learnt alot from the asking the question so many thanks for the comments and answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug. The expression

```
2 + (NSIM == 1) ? 0 : 99
```

is grouped as

```
(2 + (NSIM == 1)) ? 0 : 99
```

due to operator precedence. (The ternary conditional operator appears pretty low on the operator precedence table.)

So this evaluates to `0`, irrespective of the value of `NSIM`.

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful answer and supportive comments

Answer (score 3):

Addition subtraction has higher [precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) than Ternary conditional `?:`. As a result it turns out to be

```
(2 + (NSIM == 1)) ? 0 : 99
```

As per this ordering this is correct result.

The best would be to parenthesize every expression that you are in doubt. It's an easy way out, which is infact what you did in the second case as you have shown. It is highly unlikely that you would remember precedence of every operator.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Sorry could have accepted either answer as solution, - +1 though.